# More performant search in a list using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, set

I have 2 json responses(A & B) returned by 2 different api endpoints. The current output types are a list. They contain more than 10,000 text/string items. The json_response_A doesn't get updated often and have more items in the list than json_response_B.

I need to display items in json_response_B that doesn't exists in json_response_A. This code will work but I am not sure if it's efficient and performant.

What I'm planning to do is convert those 2 list as sets.

For example, here is our data that's been converted to sets.

```
a = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","scott","toy","church","a","b","python","medicine"}
b = {"1","2","3","ana","swingset","town","church","python"}

for item in b:
  if item not in a:
    print(item)
```

output

```
swingset
town
ana
```

It works but can the code be written even better?

Comment: Have you tried `b-a`?

Comment: looks like you need `b-a`..

Comment: `print(b-a)` or `b.difference(a)`.